# ASP Net Core - Servidor recebe múltiplas requisições GET repetidamente

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, amazon-aws

Olá, eu possuo um servidor hospedado numa instância EC2, Ubuntu Server na Amazon AWS. Ninguém está realizando requisições à este servidor, porém, logs apresentados no CloudWatch indicam múltiplas operações de GET seguidos de POST, segue abaixo as operações que são repetidas indefinidamente:

> [6/9/18 4:22:14 AM] Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET
>   http:// *MY EC2 PRIVATE IP* -
>
> [6/9/18 4:22:14 AM] Information: Executing action method
>   Api.Controllers.InicialController.HelloWorld (Api) with arguments
>   ((null)) - ModelState is Valid -
>
> [6/9/18 4:22:14 AM] Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext. -
>
> [6/9/18 4:22:14 AM] Information: Executed action
>   Api.Controllers.InicialController.HelloWorld (Api) in 0.1211ms -
>
> [6/9/18 4:22:14 AM] Information: Request finished in 0.2695ms 200
>   application/json; charset=utf-8 -
>
> [6/9/18 4:22:33 AM] Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST
>   http://coresvcs.samsungcloudprint.com/*SOMETHING*[/client](http://coresvcs.samsungcloudprint.com) application/json 116 -
>
> [6/9/18 4:22:33 AM] Information: Request
>   finished in 0.3534ms 404 -
>
> Se repete...

Essas operações acima são repetidas indefinidamente, todas iguais à acima, eu desejo entender o que está acontecendo, se é um erro na programação do meu servidor, além disso, entender porque está sendo realizando um POST depois de um GET. Como corrigir isso?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Tente capturar o endereço IP de origem dessas solicitações, podem ser robos, como dito pelo Julio, mas também pode ser alguma configuração de Load Balance para verificar se o serviço está ativo (no caso do get), já no caso da solicitação POST, deu pra ver algo sobre o samsung cloud print, pode ser que alguém tenha configurado alguma impressora nesse mesmo ip e o serviço continua "pingando" para verificar a atividade, experimente trocar o endereço ip da EC2 para verificar se essas requisições continuam. Se diver algum DNS vinculado, mude o IP mas não mude o DNS, se parar as chamas, mude o DNS para o ip atual, se voltarem as chamadas, pode ser alguém chamando direto no seu endereço DNS configurado.

Comment: Obrigado! As solicitações GET para o endereço IP privado do EC2 eram de origem do Healthy Check do EC2 (configurado para cada 30 segundos). Porém, ainda não estou entendendo o que são aquelas operações de POST do samsung cloud print

Comment: Já tentou trocar o IP ? Como disse, pode ser alguma programação existente lá no serviço da samsung para o IP que você está utilizando.

Answer (score 0):

É dificil saber exatamente, mas cuidado, o tráfego inesperado pode ser de robos, maliciosos ou não. O AWS Web Application Firewall pode ajudar, criando regras de exclusão e outras proteções. Veja uma implementação de referencia: https://aws.amazon.com/answers/security/aws-waf-security-automations/